# Automatically set window width and height to ItemsControl Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a base window which acts as a generalised container for UserControls. It works as expected, except the width and the height do not seem to be determined by the size of the child item (which with width and height set to auto, I would expect). The xaml for the base window is as follows:

```
<local:BaseView x:Class="Program.UI.Views.BaseWindowView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Program.UI.Views"
            xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Program.UI.Converters"
            xmlns:presenter="clr-namespace:Program.Presenter"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
            d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" AllowsTransparency="True">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <presenter:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=CloseWindow}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>    
<local:BaseView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converters:SystemEventToForegroundColor x:Key="SystemEventToForegroundColor" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Program;component/UI/Templates/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</local:BaseView.Resources>
<local:BaseView.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="100"/>
</local:BaseView.Foreground>
<local:BaseView.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
</local:BaseView.Background>
<Border BorderBrush="#FF838383" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,5,5">
    <Canvas Background="#E8F6F6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Width="auto">
        <Canvas.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality" Opacity="0.3" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="4"/>
        </Canvas.Effect>
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ReferenceInfo" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=InfoCanvas}"
                   Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=InfoCanvas}"
                   d:DesignWidth="294"
                   d:DesignHeight="294">

            <Grid Width="auto" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#FF838383" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource WindowHeaderControlTitle}" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FF838383" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource WindowHeaderControlCloseLabel}" MouseEnter="Label_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Label_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonUp="Label_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Content="X"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildView}"/>
            </Grid>

        </DockPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

The view is generated on the click event of an Excel ribbon button, the code-behind for which is:

```
var childView = new DatapointDefinitionsView();
childView.DataContext = new DatapointDefinitionsViewModel();

ApplicationData.Presenter.ShowView<BaseWindowView>(
    new BaseWindowViewModel(childView, ApplicationData.Presenter), true);
```

The ShowView code is:

```
    private BaseWindowView _windowView;
    public void ShowView<T>(BaseWindowViewModel viewModel, bool asModal) where T : BaseWindowView, new()
    {
        _windowView = new T
        {

            DataContext = viewModel,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            Title = viewModel.Caption,

        };
        //Width = viewModel.ChildView[0].Width,
        //Height = viewModel.ChildView[0].Height
        if (asModal)
        {
            _windowView.ShowDialog();
            _windowView = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _windowView.Show();
        }
    }
```

Setting the width and height explicitly to the child height will set the width to the specified width, but has no effect on the height. Even if it did, however, this is not a satisfactory solution as it means the values are fixed and will not update if the usercontrol dimensions change.

Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you try `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the Window?

Comment: How do you resize your window, if you set `ResizeMode="NoResize"`?

Comment: @lokusking `ResizeMode="NoResize"` was set for testing purposes as I was trying to just set the initial size without anything else at work. Usually it is set to "CanResize" which gives me a default sized window of what looks like 1600x900 (not measured it)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I had not tried this, but setting it now it results in a window of what I would assume is the minimum size (about 80x30)

Comment: So your content is bigger than that?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, the particular usercontrol in the example (DatapointDefinitionsView) has dimensions `Height="331.18" Width="464.326"`

Comment: I can't find any way to make a window behave as you describe. I assume you tried binding to ActualWidth/ActualHeight on the outermost border? E.g. name outermost border `OuterBorder` and bind Window `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=OuterBorder}"`, same with Height/ActualHeight

Comment: @EdPlunkett An update on this: No, unfortunately that technique does not work. I did find some success by binding the width and height in code-behind to that of the first itemssource element `wBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("ChildView[0].Width");` This will at least correctly pick up both initial values, however it does not mirror changes in the child control's dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this in the end, with all the desired functionality, as follows:

I bound the canvas height (in xaml) to the height of the DockPanel
`Height="{Binding ElementName=ReferenceInfo, Path=ActualHeight}"`

but the width to the ItemsControl element
`Width="{Binding ElementName=ChildUserControl, Path=ActualWidth}"`

I removed Height and Width from the DockPanel and re-enabled `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` window attribute as per @lokusking earlier suggestion.

In order to enable `CanResizeWithGrip` functionality (and have the content of the child usercontrol dynamically resize accordingly) I hooked into the window `SizeChanged` event and added the following code:

```
    private void BaseView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = sender as Window;

        if (ChildUserControl.HasItems)
        {
            var chlidControl = ChildUserControl.Items[0] as UserControl;
            var context = (BaseWindowViewModel)window.DataContext;

            // Ignore the first 3 resize events - these occur on view generation
            if (!context.InitialResizeComplete)
                if (context.ResizeOperations < 3)
                {
                    context.ResizeOperations++;
                    return;
                }

            context.InitialResizeComplete = true;

            // Subtract all fixed size elements from window dimensions
            chlidControl.Width = window.ActualWidth - (OuterBorder.BorderThickness.Left + OuterBorder.BorderThickness.Right + OuterBorder.Margin.Right + OuterBorder.Margin.Left);
            chlidControl.Height = window.ActualHeight - (OuterBorder.BorderThickness.Top + OuterBorder.BorderThickness.Bottom + OuterBorder.Margin.Top + OuterBorder.Margin.Bottom + TaskBarGrid.Height);
        }
    }
```

I've yet to determine what drives the initial 3 resize operations. My first guess was initialisation, then x, then y - but on reflection it could possibly be 1 for the baseview, 1 for the basewindow and 1 for the usercontrol. If that's the case then attached usercontrols that themselves have multiple views could prove problematic using this approach, but I've yet to test.

Hope somebody can find this useful, and thanks to those who offered help.